# Install4J - Add a startup executable on Windows and OS X check box for end user

Tags: installation, startup, install4j

I added "Add a startup executable on Windows and OS X" action to the Finish Screen of my installer. The appplication starts up on reboot and thats good but I want to display a checkbox to end user to select/unselect at  finish screen of my installer if user wants to add to startup or not just like desktop shortcuts etc. I am not able to find out how.
Can somebody please help me how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a "Check box" form component to the "Finish screen" with your question to the user and set its "Variable name" property to "addStartupExecutable".

Then, set the condition expression of the "Add a startup executable on Windows and OS X" action to

```
context.getBooleanVariable("addStartupExecutable")
```

Comment: I don't know if there is a bug in install4j but this is what is happening : I install application first time and select the option to add to startup then I uninstall and install again and unselct to add to start up - It works for windows but in Mac OSx it still launches though i unselected option second time it feelsuninstalltion is not removing from startup once added in Mac?

Comment: Login Items are not removed when uninstalled application in Mac by dragging it to trash?

Comment: No, you have to run an uninstaller. When you drag something to the trash, no executable code is invoked by the operating system.